# How to use Struct in UITableView in Swift 3.0?

Tags: ios, uitableview, struct, swift3

I'm trying to display JSON value using ***Struct*** into table view in Swift 3.0 .

I managed to display JSON value using struct into UIPickerView and it works fine. But somehow when I use the same way in table view it does not work.

Can someone help me to update my code below in order to make it work in UITableView ? Appreciate if someone can help. Thanks.

**list.php output**

```
[
    {"id":"101", "name":"name1"},
    {"id":"102", "name":"name2"}
]
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    @IBOutlet var tableview: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet var deptLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var selectBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var displayIDLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var displayNameLbl: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        deptLbl.text = "ITD"
        self.tableview.isHidden = true
        getList()
    }

    var persons = [Person]()
    struct Person {
        var id: String
        var name: String

        init?(dict: [String:Any]) {
            guard let id = dict["id"] as? String, let name = dict["name"] as? String else {
                return nil
            }
            self.id = id
            self.name = name
        }
    }

    func getList() {
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://localhost/list.php")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "dept=\(deptLbl.text!)"
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                return
            }
            if let array = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])) as? [[String:Any]] {
                self.persons = array.flatMap(Person.init)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableview.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self .persons.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "listcell", for: indexPath)

        let data = persons[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = data.id
        cell.textLabel?.text = data.name

        return cell

    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.displayIDLbl.text = self.persons[indexPath.row].id
        self.displayNameLbl.text = self.persons[indexPath.row].name
        self.tableview.isHidden = true
    }

    @IBAction func pressedBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        self.tableview.isHidden = !self.tableview.isHidden
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no `reloadAllComponents` method on a tableview.  The equivalent is `reloadData`.  In `cellForRow(at:)` you need to return the cell, not a string.  This code wouldn't even compile and the compiler would give you the errors

Comment: @Paulw11 tq for the feedback . I notice that error . . right now I have no idea what to add inside cellForRowAt and didSelectRow. can you help me to update the code above ? Thanks again.

Comment: In `cellForRow(at:)` you would put the data from your struct into a label in the cell and return the cell.  As for what you would have in `didSelectRow`, I don't know; what do you want to do when they select a row.  `persons[indexPath.row]` will give you the struct for the row that was selected.

Comment: @Paulw11 . In didSelectRow,  I want to display id value in displayIDLbl and name value in displayNameLbl.

Comment: You just need `indexPath.row` rather than `indexPath` - In a table view an `IndexPath` has a row and a section.

Comment: @Paulw11 , I have updated my code above . but I'm still having error in this line inside didselect row         "if indexPath >= self.persons{
            return
        }"

Comment: @Paulw11 and this line inside cellForRowAt "        let data = persons[indexPath.row]
        if let rid = data.id {
            cell.displayIDLbl.text = rid
        }
        if let rname  = data.name {
            cell.displayNameLbl.text = rname
        }
        return cell"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151451/discussion-between-paulw11-and-rozaimi).

Comment: The `if indexPath >=` would be `if indexPath.row >=` but it isn't necessary - how could a row be selected if it's index was > than the number of rows in the table?  And you don't need to use `if let...` for id and name, since they aren't optional.  They are guaranteed to have values, so you can just use them directly.

Comment: @Paulw11 . Ok. I already remove the line inside didSelectRow. it seems that no errors . but still having an error inside cellForRowAt. can you update on your answer ? thanks.

Comment: You need to provide some detail on the error messages.  Did you get rid of the `if let...`?

Comment: @Paulw11, yes . i have updated my code above. but it says "value of type UITableViewCell" has no member 'displayIDLbl' . .it does not recognize UIlabel

Comment: When you dequeue your cell you need to downcast to your custom cell class with `as`

Comment: @Paulw11 , you mean that I need to create another file ? is it UITableViewCell ?

Comment: If you want to have a custom cell with custom fields then yes, you need to make a `UITableViewCell` subclass.

Comment: @Paulw11. Alright . Thanks ! . it work like a charm . .

Comment: If the dictionary is supposed to contain only strings why do you use unspecified `[String:Any]` rather than expected `[String:String]`?